# Mediawiki extension to show a page's navigation trail?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list shows a "navigation trail":

```
C++ > Container library > std::list
```

I wonder if this is supported by an extension listed in http://en.cppreference.com/w/Special:Version or some custom code? How do I do the same for my own MediaWiki instance?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, MediaWiki has a bit of this functionality: if a page title contains slashes and subpages are enabled in this namespace (and they're not enabled by default in main namespace, see [`$wgNamespacesWithSubpages`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgNamespacesWithSubpages) for details), you get the following for e.g. a page "Foo/bar/baz": `< Foo | bar`.

If this poor man's solution is not enough for you, try some of the [breadcrumbs extensions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Breadcrumbs_extensions).